# What are short names of AGL services

Tags: automotive

I am working on Linux AGL platform 6.0.3 (Flounder).

There are so much AGL's services with pretty long name.

```
afm-service-agl-service-audio-4a--1.0-86e26f9--main@0.service
afm-service-windowmanager-service-2017--0.1--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-service-geoclue--1.0--main@0.service
afm-service-homescreen-service-2017--0.1--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-service-nfc--1.0-18be166--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-service-unicens--0.1-27a69f7--main@0.service
afm-service-persistence-binding--0.1-fc55736--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-service-network--1.0--main@0.service
afm-service-low-can-service--5.99--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-service-bluetooth--2.0--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-identity-service--0.1--main@0.service
afm-appli-launcher--0.1--main@0.service
afm-service-agl-service-weather--1.0--main@0.service
afm-appli-homescreen--0.1--main@0.service
```

They all are very hard to remember once I would like to start a separate service, example:

```
$ systemctl start afm-appli-homescreen--0.1--main@0.service
```

I think they will have the short names also, where can I find them ? Thks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside /usr/AGL/apps/autoinstall you will find all services.From there you can start them using afm-util start servicename